# How can I see what application is using the internet?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet

I managed to download / upload 22GB of data on Friday, and 14.76GB of that was "off peak" - between Midnight and 8 am.

I do not use the computer during those times, so I'm wondering what is using that amount.

How can I monitor which application is using so much internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nethogs` can monitor the network usage per process.

Start it with `sudo nethogs` to monitor, and then press `m` to change to monitoring the total instead of current data transfer. It should look like this:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.0

  PID USER     PROGRAM                      DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
18232 tim      spotify                      eth0       8.620      37.414 KB
6047  tim      /opt/google/chrome/chrome    eth0      10.129      13.322 KB
5279  tim      ..lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox  eth0       0.750       1.231 KB
32042 tim      /usr/bin/pulseaudio          eth0       0.703       0.844 KB
32446 tim      ..im/Programs/BTSync/btsync  eth0       1.016       0.832 KB
3018  debian-to/usr/bin/tor                 eth0       0.072       0.000 KB
?     root     unknown TCP                             0.000       0.000 KB

  TOTAL                                               21.290      53.644 KB
```

Comment: -v is not valid...I think you mean -m and I've edited it to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, just saw it. But I was testing on a Fedora and didn't think that the options would differ that

Answer (score -1):

The best option is using nmap and wireshark. Check out this tutorial...

[How to tap your network...](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-tap-your-network-and-see-everything-that-happens-1649292940)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.